# Solr, bulk delete by multiple id

Tags: php, solr

**Workflow:**

> remote source
>      -> import to mysql
>      -> select all outdated records in mysql
>      -> **send request to SOLR with all outdated records ids**
>      -> **solr delete by multiple ids** > push new records to Solr.

What is right query syntax to delete documents by multiple ids?

**I trying:**

```
id:(1 OR 2 OR 3)...
id:(1 AND 2 AND 3)
```

in php:

```
$query = sprintf('id:(%s)', implode(' AND ', $toDelete));

$solrUrl = sprintf('http://%s:%s/%s/%s', $this->solr['host'], $this->solr['port'], $this->solr['path'], $action);
        $docs = [
            'delete' => ['query' => $query]
        ];
        $http = new Client();
        $http->post($solrUrl, json_encode($docs),['type' => 'json', 'timeout' => 30]);
```

Answer (score 4):

The clue is to simply rewrite the delete request as a delete by query, and then submit all the id’s to be removed as a simple OR query. Needless to say, that’s more than fast enough and solved our problem.

To sum it up; write a delete-by-query-statement as:

**id:(123123 OR 13371337 OR 42424242 .. )**

Comment: yes, id:(1 OR 2 OR 3 ...) works but is limited to max 1000 ids.  All my query contain more than 1000 ids and not works.. That is what I now find :(

Comment: How many id's you are having totally? you can try with cron job  parallel execution like first 1000 id's are in one thread likewise..

Comment: Are there any sequences of ids? in that case you can use a range to delete those; otherwise you can up the number of max boolean clauses in the configuration, or you'll have to make multiple requests.

Comment: @Pradeepan, totally  0 TO n, I have implemented background worker.

Comment: @MatsLindh, No is random ids.

Comment: Then multiple requests, either in parallel or after each other, before issuing a commit at the end is the way to go.

Comment: I have same issue.. is there any proper solution to delete more than 1K records in 1 query?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against using a delete by query. Instead send the delete command directly via XML or JSON which is more efficient.

- JSON: `{"delete":["1","2","3"]}`
- XML: `<delete><id>1</id><id>2</id><id>3</id></delete>`